# How to reference a CloudWatch metric created by container insights for EKS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I saw an example, how it is possible to make a reference on ECS:
[How to reference a CloudWatch metric created by container insights for ECS/Fargate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164530/how-to-reference-a-cloudwatch-metric-created-by-container-insights-for-ecs-farga)

My goal is to make it similiar for EKS, to get "ContainerInsights" like Utilization, Memory etc.

I would be happy, if someone could show me an example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access any metric published by CloudWatch by [instantiating a Metric object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudwatch-readme.html#instantiating-a-new-metric-object). The list of EKS Container Insights metrics can be found [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-metrics-EKS.html).

So, for example,

```js
new cloudwatch.Metric({
  metricName: 'node_cpu_usage_total',
  namespace: 'ContainerInsights',

  // if your EKS cluster is defined in CDK, you can also reference the 
  // dimensions dynamically (instead of hardcoding as shown in this example)
  dimensions: { ClusterName: 'MyCluster', NodeName: 'MyNode' },
});
```

You can always look at the metrics in the [CloudWatch Metrics Explorer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Metrics-Explorer.html) to discover the proper metric names and dimensions to use.